npm WARN deprecated - NextJS create-next-app
When writing a NextJS app (on the Firebase platform), I get annoying warnings that I would like to know how to eliminate. Can someone help me or give me some hints ?
Below is the result of my running the command: npx create-next-app@latest
On can see at the end of the listing, 6 lines starting with:
npm WARN deprecated

These are the issues I am talking about.
me@MyMac FireBase % npx create-next-app@latest
Need to install the following packages:
create-next-app@15.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) 
✔ What is your project named? … myapp
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like your code inside a `src/` directory? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Turbopack for next dev? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the import alias (@/* by default)? … No / Yes
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/myapp.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: app-tw 


Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next

Installing devDependencies:
- typescript
- @types/node
- @types/react
- @types/react-dom
- postcss
- tailwindcss
- eslint
- eslint-config-next

npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.13.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm WARN deprecated eslint@8.57.1: This version is no longer supported. Please see https://eslint.org/version-support for other options.

added 370 packages, and audited 371 packages in 20s

137 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created myapp at /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/myapp

me@MyMac FireBase % 

.....
Then later in the process of building my app I get more serious problems,
when running the command: npm i react-firebase-hooks
as on can see below.
me@MyMac myapp % npm i react-firebase-hooks  
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@19.0.0-rc-fb9a90fa48-20240614
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@">= 16.8.0" from react-firebase-hooks@5.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-firebase-hooks
npm ERR!   react-firebase-hooks@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-26T15_05_49_809Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-26T15_05_49_809Z-debug-0.log
me@MyMac myapp % 


What are you expecting? You can't eliminate them, unless you are a maintainer of the packages via which you have a transitive dependency on those outdated packages.

That would be OK if there was no problem further down the road. That is why I want to see if there is no way to get rid of these weird warnings coming up right from start.

@jonrsharpe. I edited the post to be more precise on that matter.
